# Javascript reduce array of objects by mutual value

Tags: javascript, reduce

how can i reduce array of objects to new array of merged objects?
I have following array mixed with places and their sub areas. I want to add sub_main_places to main_places like following:

```
 "unformatted places": [
    {
      "name": "main_place1",
      "address": "place_address1"
    },
    {
      "name": "main_place2",
      "address": "place_address2"
    },
    {
      "name":"sub_main_place1",
      "address":"sub_main_place_address1"
    },
    {
      "name":"sub_main_place2",
      "address":"sub_main_place_address2"
    }
  ]
```

The result im trying to achieve is:

```
  "formatted places": [
    {
      "name": "main_place1",
      "address": "place_address1",
      "sub_area": "sub_main_place1"
    },
    {
      "name": "main_place2",
      "address": "place_address2",
      "sub_area": "sub__main_place2"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: How do you think this could be achieved? What did you try

Comment: Do the real values really end with numbers `1`, `2`, etc.? If not, how will you tell how the values should be grouped?

Comment: Yes there are numbers at the end, but there is typo, it should be underscore before the number... Idea was that split('_').pop() and compare numbers, since the number is always the one common factor, then if number match format new object from those. But from there i dont know.

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce, you can assemble an object with keys that correspond to the main address, then reference those when you encounter a sub address. At the end, you can convert the result back to an array with Object.values

```js
let unformatted_places = [{
    "name": "main_place1",
    "address": "place_address1"
  },
  {
    "name": "main_place2",
    "address": "place_address2"
  },
  {
    "name": "sub_main_place1",
    "address": "sub_main_place_address1"
  },
  {
    "name": "sub_main_place2",
    "address": "sub_main_place_address2"
  }
]

let formatted_places = Object.values(unformatted_places
  .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
  .reduce((b, a) => {
    let f = a.name.split('sub_')[1]
    if (a.name.indexOf('sub_') === 0 && b[f]) {
      b[f].sub_area = a.name;
    } else {
      b[a.name] = a;
    }
    return b;
  }, {}))

console.log(formatted_places);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tried another way:**

```js
let data_1 = {
  "unformatted places": [{
      "name": "main_place1",
      "address": "place_address1"
    },
    {
      "name": "main_place2",
      "address": "place_address2"
    },
    {
      "name": "sub_main_place1",
      "address": "sub_main_place_address1"
    },
    {
      "name": "sub_main_place2",
      "address": "sub_main_place_address2"
    }
  ]
};

let data_2 = {}

data_1["unformatted places"].forEach(function(dict) {
  var name = dict.name;
  if (name.startsWith("main")) {
    data_2[name] = dict;
  } else if (name.startsWith("sub_")) {
    let key = name.substring(4, name.length);

    if (key in data_2) {
      data_2[key]["sub_area"] = name;
    } else {
      data_2[key] = {
        "sub_area": name
      };
    }

  }
});
data_2 = {
  "formatted places": Object.values(data_2)
}
console.log(data_2);
```